# SQL combine two rows with common batch number into one line

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle SQL (select *) query that spools batch transactional information, the result of which outputs the main sender and receivers to different lines for the same transaction like below:

```
BATCH_NO    DATE      AMOUNT    SENDER_ACCT_NO  SENDER NAME RECEIVER_ACCT_NO    RECEIVER NAME   
12345678    15-May-20   103.55  400001000        ENDCORP         (null) 
12345678    15-May-20   34.55   400001000        (null)          78909909         JOHN SMITH
12345678    15-May-20   44.00   400001000        (null)          78853229         HENRY FAGIL
12345678    15-May-20   4.00    400001000        (null)          76849852        BENJAMIN HOOK
12345678    15-May-20   21.00   400001000        (null)          72555099          FELIX MAGS
12222222    16-May-20   1902.00 400000105       ZENDCORP          (null)
12222222    17-May-20   1899.00 400000105        (null)          90333300          KEN GOTL
12222222    18-May-20   3.00    400000105        (null)          90127765         JONES MAST
```

In this case, ENDCORP and ZENDCORP sent out batch payments of a total of 103.55 and 1902.00 to 4 and 2 clients respectively.

However, I would prefer my results to be in the form below:

```
BATCH_NO    DATE      AMOUNT    SENDER_ACCT_NO  SENDER NAME    RECEIVER_ACCT_NO        RECEIVER NAME
12345678    15-May-20   34.55   400001000        ENDCORP        78909909                JOHN SMITH
12345678    15-May-20   44.00   400001000        ENDCORP        78853229                HENRY FAGIL
12345678    15-May-20   4.00    400001000        ENDCORP        76849852                BENJAMIN HOOK
12345678    15-May-20   21.00   400001000        ENDCORP        72555099                 FELIX MAGS
12222222    17-May-20  1899.00  400000105       ZENDCORP        90333300                  KEN GOTL
12222222    18-May-20   3.00    400000105       ZENDCORP        90127765                 JONES MAST
```

I would appreciate guidance on how to formulate my query for this result

Comment: If the "input" you showed us is in fact the result of an outer join, it would be much easier to fix this directly in the `select` clause of your existing query. You will need to show us the full query though (or the relevant part of it, anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming when you say the query is select * that you are showing us the table structure. Otherwise we'd need more detail of the tables and your query.

If it's one table,  you just need to select where sender name is null and join to the same table on sender acct no and sender name is not null, selecting appropriate columns from each relation.

Comment: Ah cool, glad it worked. I'm a bit surprised by the table structure - if you have any say in it, it would be worth denormalising it. Please do accept the answer so it shows up as answered when people are skimming through questions. Best wishes, Chris

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use window functions to impute the name and then filter:

```
select . . .   -- columns you want
from (select t.*,
             max(sender_name) over (partition by batch_no) as imputed_sender_name
      from t
     ) t
where RECEIVER_ACCT_NO is not null;
```